# Как получить стиль по классу в SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

Испробовал много разных способов получения стиля, в первую очередь пытался использовать `getComputedStyle()`, но это не помогает, вот допустим есть svg, в нем есть, допустим, polygon у которого есть какой-то класс. Надо узнать значение `fill` и `stroke`.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 89.55 82.69"
     class="svg svg-gradient replaced-svg">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1,.cls-2{fill:none;stroke:#153e4c;stroke-width:2px;}.cls-1{stroke-linejoin:bevel;}.cls-2{stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1-2">
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.78 49.9 73.13 35.71 44.78 21.53 16.41 35.71 44.78 49.9"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="16.41 35.71 44.78 21.53 30.59 14.44 2.23 28.62 16.41 35.71"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.78 81.8 16.41 67.62 16.41 35.71 44.78 49.9 44.78 81.8"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.78 81.8 73.13 67.62 73.13 35.71 44.78 49.9 44.78 81.8"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-2" points="58.95 56.98 87.32 42.8 73.13 35.71 44.78 49.9 58.95 56.98"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-2" points="30.59 56.98 2.23 42.8 16.41 35.71 44.78 49.9 30.59 56.98"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="73.13 35.71 44.78 21.53 58.95 14.44 87.32 28.62 73.13 35.71"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.78 20.92 65.33 10.82 44.78 0.9 24.21 10.82 44.78 20.92"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.78 44.4 24.21 33.52 24.21 10.82 44.78 21.88 44.78 44.4"></polygon>
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.78 44.4 65.33 33.52 65.33 10.82 44.78 21.88 44.78 44.4"></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Получить надо с помощью JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [window.getComputedStyle()](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes)

```js
elem = document.querySelector('.cls-1');
style = getComputedStyle(elem);
console.log(style.stroke);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 89.55 82.69"
     class="svg svg-gradient replaced-svg">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1,.cls-2{fill:none;stroke:#153e4c;stroke-width:2px;}.cls-1{stroke-linejoin:bevel;}.cls-2{stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1-2">
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="44.78 49.9 73.13 35.71 44.78 21.53 16.41 35.71 44.78 49.9"></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Все супер, у меня не работало из-за того, что я с SVG работал до его вставки в DOM HTML.